# How to Serialize Object into JSON in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, nsjsonserialization

I have a Class as follows

```
Class1 *obj = [[Class1 alloc] init];
obj.id=1;
obj.Name=@"aaa";
obj.Marks=100;
```

I am adding this to NSMutableDictionary as follows

```
NSMutableDictionary* dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
[dict setObject:obj forKey:"1"];
```

So If I serialize dict object I'll get

```
{ 1:{id:1,Name:"aaa",Marks:100},2:{"id:2,Name:"bbb",Marks:70} }
```

How Can I Serailize dict object into JSON like above ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459750/serialize-custom-object-to-json-which-contains-nsmutablearray?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

Use `dataWithJSONObject:options:error:` method of `NSJSONSerialization` class.

Comment: NSJSONSerialization documentation clearly states that "All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull.". this does not answer the posed question.